# Feature Collection of random points need to be converted in Multipoint

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I know that with this function I can create n random points in the area geometry.

```
var fg_points = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints(geometry,n);
```

But it return a Feature Collection. I need to have a Multipoint.

Is there a code that gives me a Multipoint instead of a Feature Collection, or is there a command to transform the Feature Collection into a Multipoint?

Answer (score 3):

`fg_points.geometry()` will give you the union of all of the points, a `MultiPoint` type geometry.

```
var multipoint = fg_points.geometry();

print(multipoint);
```

Demo: https://code.earthengine.google.com/1ae602aec86ce234c3f53046d0f7fcd5

Comment: It works! Thank you